# How to determine if user is enabled for first release in O365/SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have a custom master page in SharePoint Online. I ran into an issue while customizing the Office 365 Suite Bar. The code I have worked well using my account as a first release customer, but does not work for non-first release users. It seems I need to use different logic in my code depending on if the user has first release. Is this possible to do in JavaScript in SPO? I checked _spPageContextInfo, but all the version information is the same

Answer (score 1):

To determine this, use the Azure AD cmdlets.

```
Connect-MsolService
Get-MsolUser -Userprincipalname user@domain.com | select ReleaseTrack
```